# VStack space at top and bottom with lazyHGrid

Tags: swiftui

I have this example. Why is there this space at top and bottom of the VStack? The borders of the inner views doesn't seem to be as high as the border of the VStack. I think it has something to do with the LazyHGrid!? Thanks for an answer.

```
 struct ContentView: View{
    let names = ["house","creditcard"]
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("skldfjsjf")
            Text("klsadjf")
            Text("lksajf")
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                LazyHGrid(
                    rows: [GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40))],
                    spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(names, id: \.self) { icon in
                        Image(systemName: icon)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
                .border(Color.orange)
            }
            .border(Color.green)
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9)
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: Gosh... how much else... look for `spacing` and set to `0` where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to SwiftUI, but I think you want the content in your VStack to be top hugging?

```
struct ContentView: View {
let names = ["house","creditcard"]
   var body: some View{
       VStack (spacing:0) { //THIS HERE FOR NO SPACE FOR VSTACK INTERNAL VIEWS
           Text("skldfjsjf")
           Text("klsadjf")
           Text("lksajf")
           ScrollView(.horizontal){
               LazyHGrid(
                   rows: [GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40))],
                   spacing: 10) {
                   ForEach(names, id: \.self) { icon in
                       Image(systemName: icon)
                           .padding()
                   }
               }
               .border(Color.orange)
           }
           .border(Color.green)
           Spacer() //THIS HERE TO MAKE IT TOP HUGGING
       }
       .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9)
       .border(Color.black)
    }
}
```